# How to create avd in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have tried making customs and other AVDs given by the Android studio , but every time I go through the whole process and click finish but I did not find the Run button anywhere from the AVD manager to run the AVD. and when I click again to the AVD Manager it has a single button of "Create a virtual device"

So I wanted to know from where I have to run the AVD

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: well its solved thanks BTW . M using 0.81